# RxJs looping over returned array

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Is there a better way using RxJS operators to loop over an array returned from an observable than this to emit a new individual ListingItem?

```
onGetItemData(){
this.dataService.getItemData().subscribe((itemData) =>
{
  this.itemDataJSON = itemData;
  this.itemDataJSON.forEach(function (value) {
    let new_listing = new ListingItem(value.label,value.market,value.name);
    console.log(new_listing);
  });
 });
}
```

The API returns a single array containing the items, so I am unable to use .map to access itemData.name

```
//-- DataService --// 
getItemData(){
 return this.http.get(this._URL, { headers })
        .pipe(map((res: Listings) => res.items))
}
```

Comment: `flatten` might be what you want. `this.http.get(this._URL, { headers })
        .pipe(flattten(), map(item => item.name))`

Answer (score 15):

Why don't just pipe a `map()` ?

```
this.dataService.getItemData()
    .pipe(
        map(itemData => {
            return itemData.map(value => {
                return new ListingItem(value.label, value.market, value.name);
            })
        })
    )
    .subscribe((listingItem) => {
        console.log(listingItem) // gives an array of listingItem
    });
```

Note that [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a JavaScript's native array function, you will use it to transform the data, by looping over each item of the array

Just for a one-liner:

```
.pipe(
    map(itemData => itemData.map(value => new ListingItem(value.label, value.market, value.name)))
)
```

Comment: The reason is due to this error on itemData.map: [ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object' any....

Is that because itemData is an object containing an array?

Comment: @user4003765 yes. But in your code you are already using `.forEach()` in your `itemData`. So is it an object or array? Unless you post a stackblitz that can reproduce the problem, else only you know your code best and we outsiders couldnt be possible try to guess every possibility on where the error is.

Answer (score 4):

I'm still learning Observables myself, but I think you can create an Observable from an Array like I did in this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbtvux

In a nutshell (in Angular 6):

```
import { from, pipe } from 'rxjs';
...
let observable = from([10, 20, 30])
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

So maybe you can pipe the switchMap operator on your observable which returns an array, something like this:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
yourArrayObservable$.pipe(
  switchMap(val => from(val))
);
```

... and then you could use map after that like so:

```
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
yourArrayObservable$.pipe(
  switchMap(val => from(val)),
  map(val => val * 42)
);
```

... at least that seems to work in my aforementioned StackBlitz.

---

Update: I think the flatMap operator also works similarly, with a single operator:

```
yourArrayObservable$.pipe(
  flatMap(val => val * 42)
);
```

Comment: Error on from(val): [ts] Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<ObservableInput<{}>>'.